# Error running Pylint on windows

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I installed pylint via pip (version 9.0.1) on a Windows 7 machine with Python 3.5.0. The installation succeeded, but invoking Pylint returns an error "RuntimeError: Inconsistent hierarchy". Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

> 14:27:19 C:\Users\user2>pylint Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 718, in dispatch
>       impl = dispatch_cache[cls]   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\weakref.py",
>   line 352, in **getitem**
>       return self.data[ref(key)] KeyError:
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 721, in dispatch
>       impl = registry[cls] KeyError:
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 170, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\pylint.exe__main__.py",
>   line 9, in    File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pylint__init__.py",
>   line 13, in run_pylint
>       Run(sys.argv[1:])   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py",
>   line 1222, in **init**
>       linter.load_default_plugins()   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\lint.py",
>   line 453, in load_default_plugins
>       checkers.initialize(self)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers__init__.py",
>   line 114, in initialize
>       register_plugins(linter, **path**[0])   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\utils.py",
>   line 992, in register_plugins
>       module = modutils.load_module_from_file(join(directory, filename))   File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\modutils.py",
>   line 272, in load_module_from_file
>       return load_module_from_modpath(modpath, path, use_sys)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\modutils.py",
>   line 233, in load_module_from_modpath
>       module = imp.load_module(curname, mp_file, mp_filename, mp_desc)   File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\imp.py",
>   line 234, in load_module
>       return load_source(name, filename, file)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\imp.py",
>   line 172, in load_source
>       module = _load(spec)   File "", line 693, in _load   File "", line 673, in
>   _load_unlocked   File "", line 662, in exec_module   File "", line 222,
>   in _call_with_frames_removed   File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers\python3.py",
>   line 100, in 
>       class Python3Checker(checkers.BaseChecker):   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers\python3.py",
>   line 501, in Python3Checker
>       'sys.version_info < (3, 0)',   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pylint\checkers\python3.py",
>   line 496, in 
>       [astroid.extract_node(x).repr_tree() for x in [   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\node_classes.py",
>   line 624, in repr_tree
>       _repr_tree(self, result, set())   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 743, in wrapper
>       return dispatch(args[0].**class**)(*args, **kw)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\node_classes.py",
>   line 613, in _repr_node
>       depth)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 743, in wrapper
>       return dispatch(args[0].**class**)(*args, **kw)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\astroid\node_classes.py",
>   line 613, in _repr_node
>       depth)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 743, in wrapper
>       return dispatch(args[0].**class**)(*args, **kw)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 723, in dispatch
>       impl = _find_impl(cls, registry)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 674, in _find_impl
>       mro = _compose_mro(cls, registry.keys())   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 662, in _compose_mro
>       return _c3_mro(cls, abcs=mro)   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 616, in _c3_mro
>       other_c3_mros = [_c3_mro(base, abcs=abcs) for base in other_bases]   File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 616, in 
>       other_c3_mros = [_c3_mro(base, abcs=abcs) for base in other_bases]   File
>   "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 620, in _c3_mro
>       [explicit_bases] + [abstract_bases] + [other_bases]   File "c:\users\user2\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\functools.py",
>   line 571, in _c3_merge
>       raise RuntimeError("Inconsistent hierarchy") RuntimeError: Inconsistent hierarchy
>
> 16:30:52 C:\Users\user2>

Comment: Same is happening on mac with python 3.5